# Convert.ToString() e .ToString()

Tags: c#, .net, string, conversão-de-tipo

Por acaso existe alguma diferença gritante entre eles? Seja em desempenho ou formas de tratar, quais são suas particularidades? Qual seria a maneira correta de se utilizar (se houver alguma diferença)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O primeiro é usado quando se deseja explicitamente converter um objeto para uma *string*. O segundo é para pegar a representação textual de um objeto. É uma diferença semântica importante que deve ser observada, mesmo que o resultado acabe sendo o mesmo. E nada garante que seja o mesmo.

Você pode aplicar o [`Convert.ToString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads) em um valor nulo que o método saberá o que fazer, retornando uma *string* vazia `""`). Já se tentar usar `objeto.ToString()` é possível que uma exceção `NullReferenceException` seja lançada. Porém isso não é garantido. Pode ser que o tipo específico tenha algum tratamento devido mesmo dentro do método de instância `ToString()`.

O método de conversão tenta usar os métodos das interfaces `IFormattable` ou `IConvertible`, quando disponível, antes de chamar a representação textual do objeto.

O [`ToString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Object_ToString) está disponível para qualquer objeto. Já o método de conversão só está disponível para alguns tipos de dados específicos (veja a lista no *link* acima).

Exemplo funcional mostrando todas situações:

```
    int? x = null;
    int y = 10;
    string z = null; //só como exemplo, não faz sentido converter string p/ string
    try {
        WriteLine($"Convert.ToString(x) = {Convert.ToString(x)}"); //fica nada
        WriteLine($"Convert.ToString(y) = {Convert.ToString(y)}"); //fica 10
        WriteLine($"Convert.ToString(z) = {Convert.ToString(z)}"); //fica nada
        WriteLine($"x.ToString() = {x.ToString()}"); //fica nada
        WriteLine($"y.ToString() = {y.ToString()}"); //fica 10
        WriteLine($"z.ToString() = {z.ToString()}"); //dá a exceção
    } catch (Exception ex) { //não faça isto, só coloquei para facilitar o teste
        WriteLine("Falhou");
        WriteLine(ex);
    }
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xiUXQn). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qb3TJo). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ConvertXToString.cs).

Answer (score 9):

Tem diferença sim... o mais correto é usar o `Convert.ToString()` levando em consideração que ele possui tratamento para valores `null`, enquanto o `.ToString()` não..

Quando você utiliza `.ToString()` você parte do principio que você está trabalhando com um objeto não nulo, correto?

**Exemplo prático:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var teste = "" ;
    teste = null;
    Console.Write(teste.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Vai resultar numa `exception` não tratada: `NullReference`.

Se eu fizer: `Console.Write(Convert.ToString(teste));`

O retorno vai ser "nada" (vai printar uma string vazia) - mas não lançará `exception`.