# Quais são as diferenças entre os seguintes casts e quando usar cada um?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, desempenho, cast

> **Casting**
>   [...] processo onde um tipo de objeto é explicitamente convertido em outro tipo, se a conversão é permitida.
>   <sub>Fonte: [Stack**overflow** em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/cast/info)</sub>

---

Supondo a seguinte situação:

`var i = 10`

Quais são as diferenças entre os *casts* abaixo e quando devo usar cada um? Também gostaria de saber sobre a performance deles, se há diferença.

1. `i.ToString()`
2. `DirectCast(i, String)`
3. `CType(i, String)`
4. `CStr(i, String)`
5. `TryCast(i, String)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [`i.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#System_Object_ToString) resulta na representação textual do objeto, não é necessariamente uma conversão como muitos pensam. Funciona para qualquer coisa. Tem mais em detalhes em [Convert.ToString() e .ToString()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121950/101).
- [`DirectCast(i, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/directcast-operator?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é outro operador de *cast* quando não se sabe qual é o tipo que será convertido e não há garantias que funcionará, lançando uma exceção se houver problemas. É o equivalente ao `(string)i` do C#, ou quase, eles não possuem exatamente a mesma semântica.
- [`CType(i, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/ctype-function?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é uma forma de conversão exclusivo do VB.NET, não funciona no C#. O operador precisa estar implementado no tipo usado. Vejo que não se costuma recomendá-lo (há quem prefira o `CStr`, há quem prefira o `DirectCast`, ainda que a recomendação oficial seja para preferi-lo. A minha é não usar VB.NET :P
- [`CStr(i)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//0zk841e9(v=vs.85)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é o operador de *cast* específico para *string* do VB.NET (exclusivo). É um conversor de dados. Tem uma performance melhor por alguma otimização do compilador.
- [`TryCast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/trycast-operator?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é o operador de *cast* que não resulta em erro, se a conversão falhar o nulo será retornado (`null` em C# e `Nothing` em VB.NET). Equivale ao `i as string` do C#. Entenda [Qual a diferença entre um cast explícito e o operador as?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47935/101)

Eu consultei algumas fontes já que VB.NET não é minha especialidade e vi que há muita controvérsia sobre o assunto e nem a documentação oficial, nem pessoas que escrevem sobre o assunto, parecem explicar adequadamente as diferenças entre eles. Mesmo que alguém poste aqui algo teoricamente conclusivo, se não for muito bem fundamentado, eu vou desconfiar.

Note que não adianta procurar desempenho se o mecanismo não fizer o que deseja. Aí estará comparando laranjas com bananas. Nesse exemplo um `DirectCast` não funciona, não é possível transformar um inteiro em texto dessa forma. E o `TryCast` resultaria em nulo.

Dependendo do que quer nenhum desses é adequado. Quando recebe dados externos que não tem controle, todos esses são problemáticos.

A performance depende também da fonte de dados. Converter *string* para *string* é muito rápido. Obter a representação textual pode ser mais rápido em que conversão. Então é complicado afirmar qual é mais rápido.

Nesse exemplo, ao que tudo indica o `CStr` é o mais rápido.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Conceptual.md).